# Anchors fail: not working first time, then working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

i developing new simple site template, but i have got problem with anchors in top menu.

1.) When you load website, you can see picture-background and menu with opacity.

2.) Now, if you click on some item in top menu, anchors failed. All anchors going to bottom of webpage.

3.) But after it, if you want to use anchors in top menu, it is working correctly.

Why?

There is top menu code:

```
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
<li class="switch"><label onclick="" for="css3menu-switcher"></label></li>
<li class="topfirst"><a href="#o-nas" style="height:px;line-height:17px;">Úvod</a></li>
<li class="topmenu"><a href="#realizace" style="height:px;line-height:17px;"><span>Realizace</span></a>
<li class="topmenu"><a href="#formular" style="height:px;line-height:17px;">Objednávky</a></li>
<li class="toplast"><a href="#kontakt" style="height:px;line-height:17px;">Kontakty</a></li>
```

And there is [link to website](http://videotest.gleton.com/). Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Your HTML on the web site is invalid. Fix the errors listed in the validator first.

Comment: I used Nu Html Checker, so HTML is valid now.